# Не работает парсинг писем с MailRu на Python, если кодировка не utf-8

Tags: python, парсер, utf-8, mail.ru

Сделал парсер писем на Python с библиотекой `imaplib`, все работает хорошо, но когда появляется письмо с кодировкой НЕ `utf-8` все ломается и выдает ошибку:

```
    print(base64.b64decode(part.get_payload()).decode())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 96: invalid continuation byte
```

Уже час пытаюсь разобраться и не могу понять, пытался и другими кодировками их раскодировать, но никак не удается и таких писем много. Может есть у кого идеи как это исправить. Код могу скинуть сюда же, если надо.

P.S. Спустя много экспериментов с кодом, но так и не нашел способа раскодировать в utf-8, и теперь вопрос ко всем читающим, знает ли кто-нибудь как сделать перебор разных кодировок?

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, образец, можно даже не реальный, того, что возвращает `part.get_payload()`. Тогда будет легче ответить на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @Chillie, при print(part.get_payload()) выводит все телефонные номера, которые указывали в сообщениях, но как только он доходит до текстовых сообщений, он не может их декодировать. А при включенной декодировке он выводит ошибку, теперь уже другую binascii.Error: Incorrect padding